# Convert List of Different Objects from DB to List of object in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

New to LINQ, I am not sure if I have put the problem into the right description.

Want to convert the vertical structure

```
[Label]    [Value]
-Field1      1
-Field2      2
-Field3      3
```

To horizontal alignment like below

```
Field1  Field2  Field3 
  1       2       3
```

Example:

The below list of Objects I get it from Microservice in JSON format

```
{
  0: {Name: "Jason" , Age: 20 , Address: "London"}
  1: {Name: "Andy" , Age: 35, Address: "Boston"}
  2: {Name: "Mike", Age : 27,Address: "California"}
  3: {Name: "Maria", Age: 22,Address: "Arizona" }
}
```

which should be converted to below format

```
{       
  0: {"Jason","Andy","Mike","Maria"}
  1: {20,35,27,22}
  2: {"London","Boston","California","Arizona"}
}
```

I took care of it at UI front but I want to format it at service end so after Json serialization the 0th,1st,2nd Index should have Name,Age and Address respectively.

Below is the Model which would hold the converted data at the backend. (it will be a list of the Model data)

```
public class Reviewer
{
 public string Name { get; set; }

 public int Age { get; set; }

 public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

I tried many ways to flatten the array and get the result into the above format still couldn't come up with the right one.

Comment: `I tried many ways to flatten the array and get the result` <= it would be helpful if you included one of those ways (pick the "best one" that did not work but got you close).

Comment: Is this a json question? This question is not clear.  What exactly are you trying to do?  You need to post your failing code

Comment: This is *transposing* and LINQ isn't the right tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples don't make sense...
If you mean you want this:

```
{       
  Name: ["Jason","Andy","Mike","Maria"]
  Age: [20,35,27,22]
  Address: ["London","Boston","California","Arizona"]
}
```

As in 3 arrays, one with the names, one with the ages and one with the addresses, you can do this:

```
var result = new Reviewer(){
    Name = initialArray.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray(),
    Age = initialArray.Select(a => a.Age).ToArray(),
    Address = initialArray.Select(a => a.Address).ToArray()
};
```

With

```
var initialArray = JsonConvert.Deserialize(@"
[
  {Name: \"Jason\" , Age: 20 , Address: \"London\"},
  {Name: \"Andy\" , Age: 35, Address: \"Boston\"},
  {Name: \"Mike\", Age : 27,Address: \"California\"},
  {Name: \"Maria\" Age: 22,Address: \"Arizona\" }
]
");
```

If that is not what you mean, you will need to clarify your question... Your examples are not valid JSON, and the model class you showed matched your data from the first example, not what you showed you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

About your class, I change int Age to string Age. Because 20,35,27,22 aren't int.

```
public class Reviewer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public static class InitializeAutoMapper
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<JArray, Reviewer>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(so =>
            string.Join(", ", so.Select(x => new JObject(new JProperty("Name", x["Name"]))).Values("Name").ToList())))

            .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => opt.MapFrom(so =>
            string.Join(", ", so.Select(x => new JObject(new JProperty("Age", x["Age"]))).Values("Age").ToList())))

            .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(so =>
            string.Join(", ", so.Select(x => new JObject(new JProperty("Address", x["Address"]))).Values("Address").ToList())));
        });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeAutoMapper.Initialize();

        string json = @"[
                        { Name: ""Jason"" , Age: 20 , Address: ""London""},
                        { Name: ""Andy"" , Age: 35, Address: ""Boston""},
                        { Name: ""Mike"", Age: 27,Address: ""California""},
                        { Name: ""Maria"", Age: 22,Address: ""Arizona"" }]";

        Reviewer reviewer = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Reviewer>(JArray.Parse(json));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: saeid : I intend to use Automapper ,which will map the List of Object returned from Entity to the Model Reviewer such that all the **same key values** will be in respective model properties.

Comment: @Jason You didn't mention to Automapper. I change it to use Automapper.